# Typecasting a character buffer to a struct coming from a socket

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, networking

I am using the following code to read data from a socket:

```
while (true) 
{

        int len = 0;
        ioctl(sd, FIONREAD, &len);
        if (len > 0)
        {
                len = read(sd, databuf, len);                   
        }

        else
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
}
```

There is a stream of structures that is coming from the socket. 
the sizes of the structs is defined an I have them.

So how can I read a struct like :

```
 typedef struct
 {
      short msglen;
      short id;
      int seqno;
 }HEADER;
```

I thought of typecasting it, but I cannot figure out how to do it. The character buffer will contain **multiple** structs one after the other. I need to read just the first 8 bytes to get the first.

Also, there is a while loop because I am receiving a continuous stream of multicast messages from the network.

Comment: `std::memcpy(&header, buffer, sizeof(header));`

Comment: @Jayesh i am on the receiving side. Also, i have no contact with the server. They have given the ip and port. And the struct definitions and sizes. Thats all.

Comment: If you are really sending the data through the wire, you need to think of endiannes, built-in data sizes and padding. Simply copying the data seems very unsafe. Look into object serialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right. But in this case the protocol has already specified that they would be sending data in little endian and I am on an intel x86 machine. They have also specified the size of POD, which matches with my machine. Also, sadly i cannot go for object serialization nevertheless as this application is very very performance centric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard compliant and safe way is to use `memcpy`:

```
HEADER header;
char buffer[/*size*/]; 

/* read data into buffer */

std::memcpy(&header, buffer, sizeof(header));
```

Modern compilers are fully capable of optimizing away the function call.

Do not try casting `buffer` with something like `reinterpret_cast`. That's undefined behavior because it violates the strict aliasing rules (you can access the stored value of an object of any type through a glvalue of `char` or `unsigned char` type, but the reverse doesn't hold).

As a side note, `typedef struct { /* ... */ } HEADER;` is a C-ism. Just do `struct HEADER { /* ... */ };`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::memcpy(&header, buffer, sizeof(header));
```